# I want to have a yes/no loop in my code, but I'm having trouble doing it (python 3.3)

Tags: python, loops

Sorry I'm just a beginner at python so this is probably a very simple question, but I have a code and I want to loop it so after the code asks the user if they want to play again and the user inputs 'yes' to restart the code and 'no' to end the code. If they input anything other than yes or no it should ask tell them to enter yes or no then ask the question again. How would I do this exactly? (I do know about while and for loops but I'm not sure how I would use them in this way)

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple one:

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter yes/no to continue")
    if a=="yes":
        gameplay()
        continue
    elif a=="no":
        break
    else:
        print("Enter either yes/no")
```

Where gameplay function contains the code to be executed

Comment: You might want to add that game playing occurs inside the if condition when a=="yes".

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the following way:

```
while True:
    # your code
    cont = raw_input("Another one? yes/no > ")
    while cont.lower() not in ("yes","no"):
        cont = raw_input("Another one? yes/no > ")
    if cont == "no":
        break
```

If you use Python3 change `raw_input` to `input`.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this:

```
# Sets to simplify if/else in determining correct answers.
yesChoice = ['yes', 'y']
noChoice = ['no', 'n']

# Prompt the user with a message and get their input.
# Convert their input to lowercase.
input = raw_input("Would you like to play again? (y/N) ").lower()

# Check if our answer is in one of two sets.
if input in yesChoice:
    # call method
elif input in noChoice:
    # exit game
    exit 0
else: 
    print "Invalid input.\nExiting."
    exit 1
```

Comment: How would you handle 'N' as the default option? If input is None: ?

Comment: @Evan - you could simply add the option in the `elif` as `elif input in noChoice or input is None` or reorder the logic to accommodate for that. You can also use a `switch-case` statement and have a `case n` and `case None` that fall into the same function call along with a `default` clause than handles the same logic if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
def playGame():
    # your code to play

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_again = 'start_string'
    while not play_again in ['yes', 'no']:
        play_again = raw_input('Play Again? (type yes or no) ')
    if play_again == 'yes':
        playGame()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this short boolean script that will maintain the loop until the if statement is satisfied:

```
 something = False
    while not something:
    inout = raw_input('type "Hello" to break the loop: ')
    if inout == 'Hello':
        something = True
```

Answer (score 1):

my approach is to just have a while loop

```
y_or_n = input("Do you want to validate another email or not? y/n: ")

while y_or_n == 'y' or email_again == 'yes':
    name = input("Enter another name ")#adapt this to your needs
    name = name.lower()#adapt this to your needs
    #your code etc
    y_or_n = input("Do you want to validate another email or not? y/n: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me:

```
while True:
    remember = input("> ")
    if remember == "Y":
        break
    elif remember == "N":
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter Y or N")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest with [`rich`](https://github.com/Textualize/rich):

```py
from rich.prompt import Confirm
do_new_run = Confirm.ask("Wanna play again?")
```