# python while - unexpected result

Tags: python, while-loop

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    val='n'
    while val != 'y' or val != 'Y':
        val = input("are we done ? [Y/n]: ")

    exit()
```

> and got quite perplexed as the result is

```
are we done ? [Y/n]: y  
are we done ? [Y/n]: y  
are we done ? [Y/n]: Y  
are we done ? [Y/n]: Y  
are we done ? [Y/n]: yes  
are we done ? [Y/n]:
```

I though perhaps [related question will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362165) but still not happy about it.
anybody knows why my first trial fails as it does?

Comment: Suppose `val` is a `str`, then the expression `val != 'y' or val != 'Y'` is *always true*.  You probably meant `not (val == 'y' or val == 'Y')`, using DeMorgane's laws, that is equivalent to `val != 'y' and val != 'Y'`.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994187/or-condition-in-while-loop-python

Comment: ah yeah .. now I see thank you (also for the link), while with or wasn't what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

It's your condition `while val != 'y' or val != 'Y'`. This will always be true, even if `val` is `y` because then it is not `Y`.

Try

```
while val != 'y' and val != 'Y':
```

This is only true if it is neither, `y` nor `Y`.

Comment: You can also tell OP to do `while val.lower()!="y"`

Comment: Yeah but this does not seem to be about efficient code but about getting the logic right.

Comment: You could suggest a better way to do it. Like how Sujay said

Comment: I know. I just wanted to tell you to include an alternative answer

Comment: @sudo You're welcome. Feel free to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    while (val:=input("are we done ? [Y/n]: ").lower()) != 'y':
        pass

    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `.lower()` method -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    val='n'
    while val.lower() != 'y': # This will work for 'y' and 'Y'
        val = input("are we done ? [Y/n]: ")

    exit()
```

You could make it better -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        val = input("are we done ? [Y/n]: ")

        if val.lower() == 'y':
            exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `or` with `and`.

This is because you want the loop to stop running only if both the conditions are true.

Final code :-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        val='n'
        while val != 'y' and val != 'Y':
            val = input("are we done ? [Y/n]: ")

        exit()
```